# Passing data from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I subclassed two view controllers.

The first one is supposed to pass data, a NSUrl object to the second one.

.m of the first one:

```
NSURL *temp = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];

UIViewController *presentationsFullScreen_ViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PresentationsFullScreen_ViewController"];

presentationsFullScreen_ViewController.urlToUse = temp;
```

.h of the second one:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PresentationsFullScreen_ViewController : UIViewController {


    NSURL *urlToUse;


}



@property (nonatomic,retain) NSURL *urlToUse;
```

It is obviously not working and not compiling,telling me essentially that I didn't subclass it and that the property urlToUse is not found on UIViewController.

How do I subclass correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the class of you destination view controller in storyboard to your custom subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct code

```
 PresentationsFullScreen_ViewController *presentationsFullScreen_ViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PresentationsFullScreen_ViewController"];
presentationsFullScreen_ViewController.urlToUse = temp;
```

Comment: thanks!!! yes that helps a lot. thank you! so obvious now. and yes i forgot to import my .h

Comment: I'm accepting this answer thanks everybody for the help but no more answers needed!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

don't forget to import the .h:

```
#import "PresentationsFullScreen_ViewController"
```

and dont instantiate the object with UIViewController but rather with the name of the subclass:

```
PresentationsFullScreen_ViewController *presentationsFullScreen_ViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PresentationsFullScreen_ViewController"];
```